# Restriction of map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ open and bounded, and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous. Let $V=f(U)$.

> Show that $f|_U^V$ is a closed map

Let $C\subseteq U$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Then it is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, so it is compact, therefore $f(C)$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}$, and since $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff it is also closed in $\mathbb{C}$.

However I have to show that $f(C)$ is closed in $V$ for $C$ closed in $U$... if I knew that $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f(C)$ would be closed in $\mathbb{C}$ by the above reasoning, so it would be closed also in $V$. But $C\subseteq U$ closed in $U$ need not to be closed in $\mathbb{R}$!

How can I get around this?

Comment: If $C$ is closed in $U$, it needs not be closed in $\Bbb R$ but $C=F\cap U$ for some closed $F$.

Comment: @Berci Can you expand please? $F$ can be taken to be also limited, so that $f(F)$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$, but how do you use this information?

Comment: We can take $F':=F\cap [a, b] $, which is compact (with $a,b$ such that $U\subseteq [a, b] $) . If we had $f(F'\cap U)=f(F')\cap f(U)$, then we'd be done.